# labeling a dendrogram after using hclust

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering

Suppose you cluster a Matrix that has a headerline in R, using hclust.

Usually one would get a labeled picture, so to speak, a dendrogram. Is there a way to make the labels of the vectors (which are in the headerline) appear within the dendrogramm?

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to help us to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you mean column names with *headerline*. Here a small example:

```
set.seed(123)
## create example matrix
m <- matrix(runif(200), ncol=10)
## create column names (A-G)
colnames(m) <- LETTERS[1:10]
## calculate distance matrix (transpose matrix, because dist use rows as individual samples)
d <- dist(t(m))
## clustering distance matrix
h <- hclust(d)
## plot it
plot(h)
```

[image]

Comment: Yes I meant about that, thank you. Ahm...is the actual Tree the only return value I get with hclust? Is there not something like a table which tells me which vector is in which cluster?

Comment: Have a look at `?hclust`. Maybe you are interested in the `merge`, `order` or `height` return value.

Comment: Not really, actually. I had a look at them, but what I actually want is something Like a list of clusters, each cluster telling me which vectors belong to it. Is that even possible?

Comment: I actually have some trouble reading dendrograms: looking at your picture, I do not see how many clusters are in there: 2, 3 or 4?

Comment: The answer: It depends. The number of clusters are depend on the height where you cut the tree. Do you look for a clustering like `kmeans`?

Comment: No I am looking for hierarchical clustering specifically. But the idea still is: you feed hclust a lot of data and get, in return, a number of clusters containing those vectors. Is not that so?

Comment: As I already said, it depends on the height where you cut the tree. In my example: 2 clusters on 2.2, 3 on 2.0, 10 on 1.2

Answer (score 0):

To get, from a hierarchical clustering `hc`, a clustering in exactly  k  clusters,
use `cutree(hc, k)`   [translated: **cut** the clustering **tree** at height to get k clusters).  This will exactly give you the desired vector length n, with contents from {1,...k}.  This applies both to `hclust()`  and to `agnes()` results, the latter from package `cluster`.